# Qt: how to set the background color of QPushButton to System-color?

Tags: qt

I have a QPushbutton on a parent-Widget. I want now to give the parent-Widget a new Background (color, image eg.) this works fine (using QPalette). However, as I am using Unix, the color from the parent-Window is propagated to the Button. Like the button has transparent background. This is fine for some cases, but sometimes I just want the parent-Widget's background to change an not the children. So that the Buttons will keep their original "system"appearance. How to achieve this? I tried a lot...but nothing gave me the desired result. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `setBackgroundRole` for the button? Maybe your button has `QPalette::NoRole` and therefore inherits its role from its parent.

Comment: no this doesn't work. The button inherits the Roles from its parent...and the parent has colors set on Role::Window, Role::Button. Changing the background role of the button doesn't change anything therefore.

Comment: Ok, I found a solution...one has to use standardPalette() (can be retrieved by QApplication::style() oder widget->style())and overwrite the whole palette of the childwidget or just single roles with the values of the standard palette.

Answer (score 0):

if your Button seems to inherit the background from the MainWindow, try setting stylesheet in this format.

```
this->setStyleSheet("MainWindow{background-color:red}");
```

Now, the background will not be inherited by your button.